# How to hide navbar on small screen without toggle menu (Boostrap)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Boostrap

```
class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"
```

with toggle menu. I want to hide whole menu on extra small screens, but preserve toggle menu icon. I try using hidde/visible options but still do't know how to do this.

Comment: Do you still want to show the menu when you click on the icon?

Comment: yes. sm+ screen normal menu, xs screen icon, which u can click and got menu. Core of problem is how to hide navbar panel (which is fixed top), but save menu icon